# Meaning of branch policy "Require at least one approval at the last iteration" unclear

Tags: azure-devops

we have configured branch policies for our default branch.

We also want to configure what happens when a new commit is pushed to make sure the new commit is properly reviewed before completing the pull request. There is the option "Require at least one approval at the last iteration". I could not find any sophisticated documentation about it. Therefore I have some questions about it:

How does this compare to the other "Reset" options that are available?
What does "last iteration" mean here? Is it the state before the new commit was pushed?

What happens to the existing votes (e.g. Approve) when a new commit is pushed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the branch policy section you can configure the `Require a minimum number of reviewers` section in a number of ways when it comes to how many approves are needed as well as if a user can approve their own changes.

When a new commit is pushed you select one of the following under the section `When new changes are pushed`

- `Reset all code reviewer votes`: All votes (approvals, reject sand waits) are reset. You basically start over from scratch
- `Reset all approval votes`: Only approval votes are reset. If users have voted `reject` or `wait` those reviews remain unchanged. This is useful if you want to avoid people bypassing reject votes by simply pushing a dummy commit
- `Require at least one approval on the last iteration`: Means that if the PR already satisfied the reviewer requirement before the most recent push, only one approval is required regardless of how many was required initially. This is useful to avoid starting a new review round with all reviewers just to fix minor things or updates based on suggestions that are not really a blocker for merging.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Unfortunately that is also what I have derived from the name of the setting. But if for "Require at least one approval on the last iteration" one approval is required only what does it mean to the already set approvals? Are they all reset or is there a kind of 2nd level approval type introduced then? I would really hope the documentation is more comprehensive for this setting.    
Use Case: 3 reviewers all have approved but PR is not completed. Now comes a new commit. What happens now?

Comment: Since the requirement of minimum approvers (let's assume it is three) was already satisfied before the last commit was pushed, only one reviewer is required before it can be merged. If you want to require all 3 to approve again you should. select either `Reset all code reviewer votes` or `Reset all approval votes`. If you select `Require at least one approval on the last iteration` the votes are *NOT* reset, but you require one additional accept vote before it can be merged. This additional accept vote can come from one of the 3 original approvers who simply vote accept again.

Comment: Let's say: First reviewer 1 and 2 approves. Then you push changes. Then reviewer 3 approves. What would happen in this case?

Comment: @AndreasStorvikStrauman Depends on several things 1) What is `Require a minimum number of reviewers` set to (i.e how many is required? 2) is `Reset all code reviewer votes` or `Reset all approval votes` selected and 3) Is `Require at least one approval on the last iteration` set?

Comment: @AndreasStorvikStrauman Assuming two reviewers are required and no resets of votes on pushes, then the requirement of two reviewers were satisfied already before the last push and the code can be merged immediately without further approvals. If `Require at least one approval on the last iteration` is selected reviewer 3 (who approves after the last push) satisfies that requirement and you can merge.

Comment: Assuming `minimum 3 reviewers` together with `require at least one approval on last iteration`

Comment: @AndreasStorvikStrauman given that votes are not reset all policies will be satisfied (in total three reviewers and one of them happened after the last push). If votes are reset there will be only one approval, which satisfies the `require at least one approval on last iteration` since it happened after the last push, but the number of reviewers will only be 1 and thus not satisfied (3 required)